# Create a custom object via the API (define the object, similar to DDL)

Tags: apex, metadata, api, partner-portal

I was looking through the Metadata API (and Partner) but can't find anywhere described how I can define via the API a custom object.

We have specific datasets which have to translate into Custom Objects in Salesforce via the API.

For instance a Home Repair dataset would include: Address, Estimate and Repair Date fields.
I want to translate this dataset into a Custom Object (named HomeRepair__c with those 3 custom fields) in Salesforce in our client's account via an API call.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, you can use the Metadata API. You want the create() call. Here's the sample xml to define the custom object from the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customobject.htm):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>
    <description>just a test object with one field for eclipse ide testing</description>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Comments__c</fullName>
        <description>add your comments about this object here</description>
        <inlineHelpText>This field contains comments made about this object</inlineHelpText>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <length>32000</length>
        <type>LongTextArea</type>
        <visibleLines>30</visibleLines>
    </fields>
    <label>MyFirstObject</label>
    <nameField>
        <label>MyFirstObject Name</label>
        <type>Text</type>
    </nameField>
    <pluralLabel>MyFirstObjects</pluralLabel>
    <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
</CustomObject>
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use this?